# Getting null pointer exception in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, integer, int

The sum of a = 2.3 and b = 1.9 and the result should be 4.

So what I tried is to round the number by converting to Int but I am getting null pointer exception.

```
fun main() {

    val a = readLine()!!.trim().toFloat()
    val b = readLine()!!.trim().toFloat()
    val result = addNumbers(a,b)
}
fun addNumbers(a:Float, b:Float):Int{ //I should not change this function
    return a.toInt()+b.toInt()
}
```

Comment: Which line produces `null pointer exception`?

Comment: val a = readLine()!!.trim().toFloat()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You are likely running in some context where there's no standard input (such as https://play.kotlinlang.org/, just for an example), because that's when `readLine()` returns `null`:

> Return the line read or null if the input stream is redirected to a file and the end of file has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

please provide the readLine() function. 
You use it as "throw an NPE if it is null" by adding !! to the call. Better would be

```
fun main() {

    val a = readLine()?.trim().toFloat()?: 0
    val b = readLine()?.trim().toFloat()?: 0
    val result = addNumbers(a,b)
}
fun addNumbers(a:Float, b:Float):Int{ //I should not change this function
    return a?.toInt()?:0+b?.toInt()?:0
}
```

there you get a 0 to add, when readLine is null

Comment: But I can't edit that main function. Is there any alternative by applying in addNumbers function?

Comment: @Phash I assume it's the default https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html.

Comment: Updated the andere. Look at the addNumbers function